# How many permutations are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

Lets assume we have any limited set `M` of any size greater than `0` and lower than `256` with some elements, e.g. `M={1,1,1,3}` or `M={1,2,2,a,b,b,a,9}`
How could you calculate the different permutations which are possible? e.g. for `{1,1,1,3}` we have the following set `C` with all possible permutations:

```
C = {(1, 1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 1, 1)}
```

another example for `M={a, a, a, b, b}`

```
C = {(a, a, a, b, b), (a, a, b, a, b), (a, a, b, b, a), (a, b, b, a, a),
     (a, b, a, b, a), (a, b, a, a, b), (b, a, a, a, b), (b, a, a, b, a),
                      (b, a, b, a, a), (b, b, a, a, a)}
```

Comment: I believe those are permutations.

Comment: @mapierce271: Yes, excuse me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the size of the sequence be $n$ and suppose there are $k$ distinct elements, where the number of occurrences of element $i$ is $p_i$. Then the formula is

$$\frac{n!}{p_1!p_2!\cdots p_k!}$$

This is because $n!$ is the number of permutations where all elements are distinct, and for any such fixed permutation there are $p_i!$ ways to permute elements of type $i$ without changing the permutation.